# Problem with union containing a glm::vec2 (non-trivial default constructor)

Tags: c++, unions, glm-math

I have a the following struct:

```
struct Foo
{
    union
    {
        glm::vec2 size;
        struct { float width, height; };
    };

    Foo() = default;
};
```

If I create an instance of `Foo` with `new`, I get the following error:

```
call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'Foo'
```

Note that I've read a few answers on SO, all are talking about using placement-new, but I did not fully understand how to apply that to my simple test-case.

Comment: How about `std::variant`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I think it's C++17. I have only access to C++14 right now

Comment: It is indeed C++17, but there are libs (as boost) which provide it for C++14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At most one non-static data member of a union may have a brace-or-equal-initializer. [Note: if any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union. — end note ]

The relevant part is

> if **any** non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial [member function] [...], [then] the corresponding member function of the union **must be user-provided** or it will be **implicitly deleted**.

So you will have to manually implement the constructor and destructor (and if you need them also the copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator and move assignment operator).

The compiler can't provide a default constructor because there's no way it could know which of the union members should be initialized by the default constructor, or which union member the destructor needs to destruct.

So using the default constructor or trying to `=default;` it won't work, you'll have to provide user-specified implementations.

---

A basic implementation could look like this:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    bool isVector;
    union
    {
        std::vector<float> vec;
        struct { float width, height; };
    };

    // by default we construct a vector in the union
    Foo() : vec(), isVector(true) {

    }

    void setStruct(float width, float height) {
        if(isVector) {
            vec.~vector();
            isVector = false;
        }
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;        
    }

    void setVector(std::vector<float> vec) {
        if(!isVector) {
            new (&this->vec) std::vector<float>();
            isVector = true;
        }

        this->vec = vec;
    }

    ~Foo() {
        if(isVector) vec.~vector();
    }
};
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/9ETh9vsav)

Note that you need to manually manage the lifetime of the union members, since the compiler won't do that for you.

In case the active union member is the `struct`, but you want to activate the `vector` member, you need to use placement new to construct a new vector in the union.

The same is true in the opposite direction: if you want to switch the active union member from the `vector` to the `struct`, you need to call the `vector` destructor first.

We don't need to clean up the `struct`, since it's trivial, so no need to call it's constructor / destructor.

---

If possible i would recommend using [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`boost::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead, since those do exactly that: they keep track of the active union member and call the required constructors / destructors as needed.

Comment: One thing I would have added to the answer is that the one of key differences between default and defaulted constructors is that the latter always performs initialization for members while the former could omit the initialization of members and allow the code in this case to compile.

Comment: @DamirTenishev  in this case both wouldn't compile though since the default constructor is required to be deleted when one union member has a non-trivial constructor. so not specifying it or defaulting it leads to it being `=delete;`'ed regardless (unless i missed something) [defaulted constructor](https://godbolt.org/z/Yn5Mbner7) - [default constructor](https://godbolt.org/z/44zM6WoY4)